# How to properly call functions in tensorflow

Tags: function, tensorflow

Given the following code, where `begin` is an input to the function `sample_text()` at the same time  it is its output. I want to call the function `sample_text()` 200 times where its output(`begin`) is the input in the next iteration. However my initial `begin` is `begin=next_element[0]` is from the `tf.data.Dataset` while subsequent begin is from the function `sample_text()`. My question  is: if I do `sess.run(begin)`, which `begin` is executed ? this `begin=next_element[0]` line  or `begin=self.sample_text(hprev,begin,p_s)`,please help

```
begin=next_element[0]
begin=self.sample_text(hprev,begin,p_s)
with tf.Session() as sess:   
           for j in range(200):
                  sample=sess.run(begin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `sample_text` function builds on top of your already existing `begin` node in your TensorFlow graph, then when you assign the Python variable named `begin` to the output of this `sample_text` function, there is nothing to worry. When you run `session.run(begin)`, both the nodes in your graph are run.

If however, you don't build on top of the first `begin` variable in `sample_text` function, the initially assigned node will become unreachable for your subsequent code. And when you run `session.run(begin)`, only the output node of your `sample_text` will be run.

Comment: @ser1190882 thanks for this.  If both of them run, which one will be the input of sample_text()  in the next iteration ?

Comment: Input in the subsequent iterations will be the second `begin`.